# problem executing multiple SQLite statements from a single file

Tags: c#-4.0, sqlite, pinvoke

I've been writing a thin wrapper around SQLite using P/Invoke, and I'd like to give it the ability to read statements from file (for bootstraps, etc.).  I wrote the following in a file:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(Col1 INTEGER,
 Col2 TEXT);

INSERT INTO Test (Col1, Col2) VALUES (1, 'test1');
INSERT INTO Test (Col1, Col2) VALUES (2, 'test2');
```

This file is read via File.ReadAllText(), prepared via sqlite3_prepare(), and executed via sqlite3_step().  This process has successfully prepared and execute single-line SQLite statements.

What happens is that the table is created, but neither insert statement is run.  What do I need to do in order to be able to insert multiple statements in a single string?

Comment: Are you aware of System.Data.SQLite http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/?

Comment: I am, but I wanted the experience of writing a P/Invoke wrapper - this is my first project with it and it's going surprisingly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  It turns out that sqlite3_step() steps only through one statement at a time.  As a result, you need to call sqlite3_step() once for each statement in your string.  This gets a little involved, since the return code SQLITE_DONE returns no matter how many statements you've executed; I'm currently doing a semicolon count before I execute the string.  Alternatively, you can just use sqlite3_exec() if you don't want to deal with the looping business.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a `GO` after each statement. It will be something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(Col1 INTEGER,
 Col2 TEXT);

GO

INSERT INTO Test (Col1, Col2) VALUES (1, 'test1');
INSERT INTO Test (Col1, Col2) VALUES (2, 'test2');
```

More information about [GO here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

Comment: GO is SQL Server. The question was about sqlite.

Comment: @MyOtherMe, Can you please specify the relevant statement in SQLite.